Make Modal Dialog into Alert in Google Apps Script
This code is made through ChatGPT. I want to change the modal dialog box into an alert but if I do that the PDF file that will be opened in new tab will not work. is there other way to make it?
function generateCPDCertificate() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var certificateSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Certificate");
  
  // Check if AG cell needs to be updated
  var sheetName = certificateSheet.getRange("D4").getValue();
  var targetSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var targetCell = targetSheet.getRange("D:D").createTextFinder(certificateSheet.getRange("D6").getValue()).findNext();
  var agCell = targetCell.offset(0, 28); // Assuming AG is 28 columns to the right of D

  if (agCell.isBlank()) {
    // Define the range to be included in the PDF
    var range = certificateSheet.getRange("A1:A30");

    // Define the filename
    var filename = certificateSheet.getRange("D4").getValue() + "_" + certificateSheet.getRange("B6").getValue() + "_" + certificateSheet.getRange("D6").getValue() + ".pdf";

    // Export the range as a PDF
    var url = spreadsheet.getUrl();
    var exportUrl = url.replace(/\/edit.*$/, '') + '/export?format=pdf&size=A4&portrait=true&fitw=true&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenum=false&gridlines=false&horizontal_alignment=CENTER&vertical_alignment=TOP';

    var options = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      }
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl + "&gid=" + certificateSheet.getSheetId() + "&range=A1:A30", options);
    var blob = response.getBlob().setName(filename);

    // Create or get the "CPD Certificate" folder
    var folderName = "CPD Certificate";
    var folderIterator = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
    var folder;
    if (folderIterator.hasNext()) {
      folder = folderIterator.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName);
    }

    // Delete existing files in the "CPD Certificate" folder
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      file.setTrashed(true);
    }

    // Save the PDF file to "CPD Certificate" folder
    var pdfFileInDrive = folder.createFile(blob);

    // Set permissions to 'anyone can view'
    pdfFileInDrive.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  
    // Open the PDF file using the Mozilla PDF Viewer
    var pdfUrl = pdfFileInDrive.getUrl();
    var message = "The PDF file is now open in the new tab.";
    var html = '<div style="width: 300px; height: 150px;">' + message + '</div><script>window.open("' + pdfUrl + '", "_blank");</script>';
    var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);

    // Show the modal dialog
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, "Generate CPD Certificate");
    
    // Update AG cell with today's date
    agCell.setValue(new Date());
  } else {
    // Display message if AG cell is not blank
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("This certificate is already printed: " + agCell.getValue());
  }
}

I am also just resizing the modal dialog if I can't change it into an alert but I also failed. can someone help. Thank you.

I cannot understand the difference between "Modal Dialog" and "Alert" you expect. Can I ask you about the details of it? By the way, about I am also just resizing the modal dialog if I can't change it into an alert but I also failed., in this csae, how about modifying var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html); to var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(500).setHeight(500);? Please adjust the values of 500 of .setWidth(500).setHeight(500).

Sorry if that is confusing you, what I mean about the "Alert" is I want to make the message that is inside the Modal Dialog "The PDF file is now open in the new tab." into like when the message "This certificate is already printed: Date" appears in the screen. but if I change that, the part where the PDF file will open in the new tab will not work.

Thank you for replying. About I want to make the message that is inside the Modal Dialog "The PDF file is now open in the new tab.", I think that when your script is run, the opened dialog shows "The PDF file is now open in the new tab.". How about this? And, I cannot understand but if I change that, the part where the PDF file will open in the new tab will not work. Can I ask you about the details of it?

Sorry if I can't explain it fully, If I change this line: SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, "Generate CPD Certificate"); then the PDF file will not open in the new tab. I am trying to just display the message as "Alert" but still open the PDF file in new tab but if I remove that line or change it, the PDF file will not open in the new tab.

Thank you for replying. About If I change this line: SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, "Generate CPD Certificate"); then the PDF file will not open in the new tab. I am trying to just display the message as "Alert" but still open the PDF file in new tab but if I remove that line or change it, the PDF file will not open in the new tab., although, unforutnately, I cannot know your Spreadsheet, in your situation, agCell.isBlank() is false?

It would probably be easier to answer your question if you shared a link to the spreadsheet with the test data.

Here is the link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m8e_jYjUdXoQctf8xW_9mhYfavSC_wTK-MZM9zgp12Q/edit?usp=sharing

Why do you want to replace a modal dialog with an alert?

I want to replace it because I can have an OK button and set a code on it when clicked.

Is this sample output similar to what you're looking for?

@Saddles yes, like that kind of output. I want to put the code for inserting the date if the yes button is clicked.

Can you share what you'd like to happen when Yes and No is selected so that I may update my answer?

In the answer, if Yes is selected, it also puts a date on the cell defined in the variable agCell. If the same thing is done and there's already a date on it, it'll give the message that the PDF has already been printed.

SUGGESTED SOLUTION
You can achieve what you'd like by changing the script from:
    var message = "The PDF file is now open in the new tab.";
    var html = '<div style="width: 300px; height: 150px;">' + message + '</div>window.open("' + pdfUrl + '", "_blank");';
    var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);

    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, "Generate CPD Certificate");

    agCell.setValue(new Date());
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("This certificate is already printed: " + agCell.getValue());
  }

To:
    var alert = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Generate CPD Certificate", "Do you want to proceed with generating the CPD certificate?", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

    if (alert == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
      var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<script>window.open("' + pdfUrl + '");google.script.host.close();</script>');
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Opening PDF...');
      agCell.setValue(new Date());
    } else {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Operation Cancelled");
    }
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("This certificate is already printed: " + agCell.getValue());
  }

The full code would become:
function generateCPDCertificate() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var certificateSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Certificate");

  var sheetName = certificateSheet.getRange("D4").getValue();
  var targetSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var targetCell = targetSheet.getRange("D:D").createTextFinder(certificateSheet.getRange("D6").getValue()).findNext();
  var agCell = targetCell.offset(0, 28);

  if (agCell.isBlank()) {
    var filename = certificateSheet.getRange("D4").getValue() + "_" + certificateSheet.getRange("B6").getValue() + "_" + certificateSheet.getRange("D6").getValue() + ".pdf";

    var url = spreadsheet.getUrl();
    var exportUrl = url.replace(/\/edit.*$/, '') + '/export?format=pdf&size=A4&portrait=true&fitw=true&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenum=false&gridlines=false&horizontal_alignment=CENTER&vertical_alignment=TOP';

    var options = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      }
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl + "&gid=" + certificateSheet.getSheetId() + "&range=A1:A30", options);
    var blob = response.getBlob().setName(filename);

    var folderName = "CPD Certificate";
    var folderIterator = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
    var folder;
    if (folderIterator.hasNext()) {
      folder = folderIterator.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName);
    }

    var files = folder.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      file.setTrashed(true);
    }

    var pdfFileInDrive = folder.createFile(blob);

    pdfFileInDrive.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);

    var pdfUrl = pdfFileInDrive.getUrl();

    var alert = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Generate CPD Certificate", "Do you want to proceed with generating the CPD certificate?", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

    if (alert == SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
      var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<script>window.open("' + pdfUrl + '");google.script.host.close();</script>');
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Opening PDF...');
      agCell.setValue(new Date());
    } else {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Operation Cancelled");
    }
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("This certificate is already printed: " + agCell.getValue());
  }
}


This uses alert(title, prompt, buttons) for the prompt and showModalDialog(userInterface, title) with the Window: open() method to open the PDF file in a new tab. close() is used to have the modal dialog box closed once the new tab opens. I've also removed var range = certificateSheet.getRange("A1:A30"); from the script since it wasn't in use.

OUTPUT


I tried running your suggested code just now but when I clicked the Yes button the modal dialog just display "Opening PDF... window.open("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SO0-49ueMOlj13aw2umA6b5ykEzONr6T/view?usp=drivesdk");google.script.host.close();.

When Yes is selected in the alert, the modal dialog box will open briefly and say Opening PDF.... It automatically closes once the generated file is opened on a new tab. You may review my example output in the answer to see what it does. If that's not what you'd like to do, please share what you'd like to do when Yes is selected.

I like the output in your code and want to use it, What I mean in my last comment is that the modal dialog just shows the Opening PDF and did not close and show the pdf file like in the output so I don't know why it did not work when I copy your code.

Apologies. I missed adding <script> and </script> on the userInterface variable when I pasted the script. I've updated my answer, and you may try to see if it now works. Also, I used OK and Cancel as the buttons in the alert because of your previous comment, I want to replace it because I can have an OK button and set a code on it when clicked.
